# Error in creating new project in Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to create a new html css project in cordova in windows platform.

`cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

gives following output

```
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.example.hello" 
at location "D:\codpro\hello"
Downloading cordova library for www...
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
at ClientRequest.onError (C:\node\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-
lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:159:17)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:833:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

I configured proxy using

```
npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@domain.tld:<port_number>
```

What wrong I am doing?

Comment: Make sure your password does not have the symbol '@'. If it does, you will have to use '%40' instead of it.

Comment: my password contains @ and it is working with @. There was proxy issue that I have fixed by setting npm proxy.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting to know. But if you were able to fix that issue somehow, then great. Also, just a friendly advice, do not post credentials or corporate proxy details on public forums :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just thought that this could be of help to someone

In my case it was the reverse. I had set the "http-proxy" but not the "https-proxy" (the secured http proxy) and got following error

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
    at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Once it was set through 'npm config' the project was created. 
So it looks like it is safe to configure both these properties with exactly the same values.